# Is there a way to run subprocesses in parallel?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, parallel-processing, subprocess, snmp

I am a newbie in Python.

I am trying to run the following script in my test environment to create a csv file with printer's IPs and their counters.
Is it possible to run all the IPs in my list in parallel?

```
import subprocess, csv
f = open("Printer_SNMP.csv", "w", encoding='UTF8', newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")

ips = ["192.168.0.10"]
for i in range (11,25):
    ips.append("192.168.0."+str(i))

for ip in ips:
    counter = (subprocess.getoutput('snmpwalk -c public -v 2c ' + ip + ' .1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.43.10.1.1.12.1.1')).split()[-1]
    if not counter.isdigit():
        counter = "NaN"
    writer.writerow([ip, counter])    
f.close()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at multiprocessing library (https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/multiprocessing.html), there is exactly what you need in the examples.

Comment: I don't unserstand a word of it.... because it's in french ;)
No but seriously, thank you! I'll go over it.

Comment: I'm sure you can handle that ;)